# Tagging a github contributor within the code

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a github repository with another contributor. Sometimes when I'm working on an area of code I leave comment tags to draw attention to code which needs more work or re-factored.

It often comes up that a particular `#TODO` comment is for a specific other contributor who has more knowlege in that area. Is there a way I can put `@ContributorName` within the comment so that it's brought to their attention when the commit is pushed to github?

At the moment my alternative is:

1. Raise an issue
2. Link to the code (e.g. as described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-your-work-on-github/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet))
3. Tag the contributor in the issue so they get notified

Alternatively could raise the issue directly from the code as described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-your-work-on-github/opening-an-issue-from-code) which perhaps saves half a step, but being able to tag contributors directly from the uploaded code would be really handy.

I've tried googling but either this can't be done or maybe I'm missing the right search term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe GitHub has this feature.  In general, leaving notes specific to individuals in the code isn't a best practice, since code is typically shared.

You could either create a GitHub Action to notify the contributor automatically by leaving a comment when you push such a commit, or you could instead review your own code, pinging the proper reviewer in the message.  But beyond that, I don't believe such a feature exists.